# Play/Pause Btn on Nivo Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider, nivo-slider

Does anyone know if there is way to add Play/Pause button to Nivo slider?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 5):

Add the code below to your jquery ready function. The code adds two buttons for start and stop. The advantage of this code is that you don't have to modify the nivoslider.js. ;-)

```
var slider = jQuery('#slider');
var nivoStartStopControl = jQuery('<div class="nivo-startstopNav"></div>');

slider.after(nivoStartStopControl);
nivoStartStopControl.append('<a href="#" id="nivoStart"><span>START</span></a> <a href="#" id="nivoStop"><span>STOP</span></a>');

jQuery('#nivoStop').click( function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   slider.data('nivoslider').stop();
});

jQuery('#nivoStart').click( function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   slider.data('nivoslider').start();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code inside nquery.nivo.slider.js on the line 627

```
jQuery('#pause').click(function(){
    if(!$(element).data('nivo:vars').stop){
        $(element).data('nivo:vars').stop = true;
        trace('Stop Slider');
    } });

jQuery('#play').click(function(){
    if($(element).data('nivo:vars').stop){
                     $(element).data('nivo:vars').stop = false;
                     trace('Start Slider');
                } });
```

From: http://support.dev7studios.com/discussions/nivo-slider/1949-how-to-add-play-and-pause-button-on-the-image-slider

Answer (score 0):

First, insert the 2 buttons in your page, stack them at the same position and give them the IDs Pause and Play.

Then, add these lines of code in the `<head>` section of your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#Pause").click(function () { 
       $('#Pause').fadeOut(200); 
       $('#Play').fadeIn(200); 
       $('#Slider').data('nivoslider').stop();
      });
    $("#Play").click(function () {
        $('#Play').fadeOut(200);
        $('#Pause').fadeIn(200);
        $('#Slider').data('nivoslider').start();
      });
});</script>
```

Comment: how do you add these buttons in the slider ?

Comment: [You can see full coding here](http://gasolicious.com/storefront-elegance-slider-navigation/)